# How to find the size of a column in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, ssms-2017

Is there any command for sql server that I can run and see the size of columns in a table? I need to know which column is leaving a heavy table

I've already tried to run some commands, but the only one I found was to see the total size of the table, and I need the size of the column?

Comment: What do you mean by the "size of the column"? You could get the number of rows in the table (using the `sys` objects) and then multiply it by the size of its data type (for example 4 for an `int`), which would get you, roughly, the size of the data in that column. That, of course, doesn't take into account compression or anything.

Comment: A column can have a fixed or variable length, but what you're most likely interested in is the total amount of data contained in all rows for that column specifically, which is independent of its length (if variable). There are no fast ways of getting that, but there are obvious slow ways (`SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, DATALENGTH(<column>))) FROM Table`). This can be sped up a bit by sampling rows (i.e. `TABLESAMPLE`) and assuming the distribution of data across columns is roughly the same for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
T AS (SELECT COL_LENGTH('sys.objects', 'name') AS COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE)
SELECT COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE,
       SUM(LEN(name)) AS VOLUME_CHARS, SUM(DATALENGTH(name)) AS VOLUME_BYTES
FROM   sys.objects CROSS JOIN T
GROUP  BY COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE
```

Will give you :

- the length in byte of the column
- the chars volume amount for all table values
- the byte volume amount for all table values

In the query I use table "sys.objects" and column "name"

Answer (score -1):

Here are two queries on the same table and the results.

```
USE master; -- version 2019

WITH T AS (SELECT COL_LENGTH('sys.objects', 'name') AS COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE)
SELECT COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE,
       SUM(LEN(name)) AS VOLUME_CHARS, SUM(DATALENGTH(name)) AS VOLUME_BYTES
FROM   sys.objects CROSS JOIN T
GROUP  BY COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE;

COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE VOLUME_CHARS VOLUME_BYTES
----------------- ------------ ------------
256               2268         4536

WITH T AS (SELECT COL_LENGTH('sys.objects', 'type_desc') AS COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE)
SELECT COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE,
       SUM(LEN(type_desc)) AS VOLUME_CHARS, SUM(DATALENGTH(type_desc)) AS VOLUME_BYTES
FROM   sys.objects CROSS JOIN T
GROUP  BY COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE;

COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE VOLUME_CHARS VOLUME_BYTES
----------------- ------------ ------------
120               1717         3434
```

In table result:

- "COLUM_LENGTH_BYTE" means exactly the length of the column in bytes...
- "VOLUME_CHARS" means exactly the total volume of chars stored in the column...
- "VOLUME_BYTES" means exactly the total volume of bytes stored in the column...

This is based on that the question asks (point 1 - I quote) "size of columns" which can tell the length of the type of columns, and that it continues on to ask (point 2 - I quote) "need to know which column is leaving a heavy table" which seems to indicate that it is trying to find out the volume of data from a column. Therefore:

1. **the size of the type**, which answers point 1
2. **the volume of a column** which answers point 2 with two versions, in terms of number of characters and in terms of bytes

Answer (score -3):

Use COL_LENGTH() to Get a Column's Length in SQL Server